# I need to fix the carousel to a specific size and the images to fit inside the carousel

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to fix the carousel to a specific size and the images to fit inside it. There is no problem in mobile view, but on computers the images fill the screen and then I have to scroll down to see the carousel indicators. What should I do?

CSS Code:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, 
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its not full width slider u shouuld put ur slider inside col or container see code below for ref

if its full width slider put it inside `container-fluid`

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     ur carousel code should be here
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if ur using full width container

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     ur carousel code should be here
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im using full width container.I thing my problem is with the height of image.

Comment: @Aswin check my updated answer, if u could show some demo or something we could help u better, if u think my answer help u, u can upvote it or/and marked as accepted